# How to animate listview to show one by one?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-animation

I have code to animate a listview but i dont know to change that code to be show list one by one.

```
  float initialTranslation = (mLastPosition <= position ? 500f : -500f);
          convertView.setTranslationY(initialTranslation);

      convertView.animate()
              .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.0f))
              .translationY(0f)
              .setDuration(500l)
              .setListener(null);

      // Keep track of the last position we loaded
      mLastPosition = position;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the library :

https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

for listview animation. it works like a charm

Library Description:-

ListViewAnimations is an Open Source Android library that allows developers to easily create ListViews with animations. Feel free to use it all you want in your Android apps provided that you cite this project and include the license in your app.

here is the library demo link:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.listviewanimations

Also u can use the new recyclerView which provides inbuilt animation for addition , removal of items